# Exercise 1.1 6 from Chung's - A Course in Probability Theory

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

The statement of exercise 1.1.6 is : 
Given any extended-valued $f$ on ($-\infty$,$\infty$), there exists a countable set $D$ with the following property. For each $t$ (there is no mention where $t$ belongs to..), there exist $t_n \in D$ with $t_n \rightarrow t$ such that $f(t)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(t_n)$. This assertion remains true if "$t_n\rightarrow t$" is replaced by "$t_n\downarrow t$" or "$t_n\uparrow t$". [This is the crux of "separability" for stochastic processes. Consider the graph $(t, f(t))$ and introduce a metric]

As I said, Chung has no metion whether $t \in $($-\infty$,$\infty$) or $t\in D$.
Contextually, I thought $t \in D$ because $f$ may be discontinuous for some $t$.
 
I had no idea with Chung's hint so I tried to solve this with another way. My idea is:

If $f$ is continuous on ($-\infty$,$\infty$), then take $D$ as set of rational number $Q$.
If not, consider a set $D_f = \{x : f$ is not continuous at $x \}$. And then take $D = Q\cap D_f$. Am I right? Am I missing something? If there is other way to solve the exercise, please let me know.

Comment: This exercise is definitely about "distribution functions" which are non-decreasing. Then one can take $D$ to be any dense countable set containing the set of points of discontinuity of $f$ (which is at most countable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think $f$ don't have to be restricted non-decreasing, because $f$ is any extended-valued function according to the statement of exercise.

Comment: You're right, and the hint also points to such meaning. Need to think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach leads nowhere, since $D_f$ can be uncountable.

Instead, as the exercise suggests, one has to look at the graph $G = \{(t,f(t))\mid t\in \mathbb R\}$ of $f$. As the extended real line is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, we can assume $f$ to be real-valued, so that $G\subset \mathbb R^2$.

Now for any rectangle $Q=(r_1,r_2)\times (q_1,q_2)$ with rational $r_1,r_2,q_1,q_2$ and such that $Q\cap G \neq \varnothing$, choose a unique point $(t_Q,f(t_Q))\in G$. Setting $D = \{t_Q\}$, we get the first part.

Per the monotone (say, increasing) convergence part, for any $Q$ such that $Q\cap G\neq \varnothing$ take the point from $G$ with minimal first coordinate, if it exists, otherwise take a sequence of points from $G$ such that their first coordinates converge to $\inf \{t\mid (t,f(t))\in Q\}$. I leave for you to prove that the first coordinates of the taken points form a countable set $D$ with desired property.

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation.